# After merge files still outdated

Tags: android, git, git-merge

I have  two branches

- dev
- sprint5

when I merge form **dev** (after solving some bugs and adding features) into **sprint5**
IDE  show me strings.xml file as conflict file, so I solved conflicts manually
and click applied, and merge is **done**

but when I compare dev with sprint5 (this current checked one)
I found a file `File.kt` its code is `sprint5 version` not `dev version` (although IDE did not show it to me when merge)

[**Note**]

`File.kt` **did not changed** at `sprint5 branch`

Comment: Is File.kt being ignored via `. gitignore'?

Comment: i checked `.gitignore` it is not added there.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe  file.kt wasn't staged by accident, try to stage/add file and then re-merge.

Steps:

1. checkout dev.
2. add/stage file.kt
3. commit.
4. checkout sprint5
5. merge dev into sprint5